# Creating a splash screen in Sencha Touch for different mobile devices resolutions 

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch, stylesheet, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha touch 1.1, and the application has to be portable across multiple mobile platforms such as android, iPhone, iPad and blackberry. I need to have splash screen at start up, and I am using the body background property to get the splash screen done.

```
<body bgcolor="0000" style="background-image: url('images/background.png');"></body>
```

I used this code in my app:

```
onReady: function() {
        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen : true,
            html : "Start Up Screen Test"
        });
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me do this for devices with multiple resolutions and in a generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to get through to your answers. Different image with resolutions for different size screens of blackberry.
http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the spash screen for phone/tablet this way:

```
Ext.regApplication('App', {

    icon: 'public/resources/images/Icon.png',

    tabletStartupScreen: 'public/resources/images/tabletImage.png',

    phoneStartupScreen: 'public/resources/images/phoneImage.png',

    glossOnIcon: true,

    fullscreen: true,

    launch: function() {
    }
});
```

Comment: how could we manage with the blackberry mobiles. we have different resolutions. how could we fix that.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS. The Icon gets displayed, but not the splash screen.