# Working with images in Sencha Touch for different Resolution Touch Device

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm planning to use Sencha Touch 2.x for my websites mobile (Light weight) view.

I am new to Sencha development. I know HTML 5 very well. Couple of things I would like to know before I would proceed with the development.

1. How Sencha manages the images. As I am planning to work with different resolution touch devices (i.e. iphone4s, iphone 5, iPad, Android and Blackberry 10). I know media query that used in HTML 5. Do we need to pass different images for each resolution or sencha will compare image for each resolution. (FYI... I also come across also [How to add images for different screen resolutions in sencha touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209030/how-to-add-images-for-different-screen-resolutions-in-sencha-touch) suggest the HTML5 media query. Is it the only way? and also refer [Creating a splash screen in Sencha Touch for different mobile devices resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008313/creating-a-splash-screen-in-sencha-touch-for-different-mobile-devices-resolution)  which is for splash screen)
2. Is it support Retina Display? (i.e. @2x in iOS). if not than how we can manage the retina display images.

Thanks in advance for any valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) For simplicity's sake, I personally go with using the highest resolution/size for each overall platform (Android, iPhone, Blackberry). The phones will scale the images accordingly. It just makes things way simpler; the only reason in my mind to not do this is if you have a truly massive total image size and optimizing is the difference between >10mb. Any time a phone has to scale any images, there is apparently a small performance hit, but it's ultimately not noticeable at all to me.

2) Sencha supports retina display. As long as you use a sufficiently high resolution image, it will be scaled properly. Make sure to include retina display [splash screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) and [app icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html), of course.

Comment: do we need to specify Image Size for any device during development? (i.e. for iPhone 320 x 480)

Comment: Nope, all you need is the relative pixel size for each image (what you would declare normally, ie: "height:200px;width:100px"). Everything will be run in the background to determine what that ends up being with regard to image scaling.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Prado for quick response, This is definitely help me.

Comment: You got it! Glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about Sencha.io.....it can automatically resize images for the device, delivering a smaller version so downloads are quicker. Have a read here:

http://www.sencha.com/products/io/

and see an example here:

http://extdesenv.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-mobile-flickr-app-with-sencha-touch-2/

:-)